# Error in Form Submission to PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm just a beginner to HTML and PHP, and when I am running this form, everytime I submit, the php file returns false and echos Error. I am assuming it has to do with the fact that 'message' is still empty. What is wrong with the following code?

```
 <form id="register-form" name = "register-form" class="text-left" method="POST" action = "inp.php" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
        <div class="main-login-form">
            <div class="login-group">

                <div class="textarea-container">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                            <div class="textarea-size" id = "message" name = "message"></div>
                            </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="login-button" w><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="etc-login-form">
            <p><font color = "white"></font> <a href="log.html"><font color = "black"></font></a></p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

> inp.php

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if( empty($_POST['message']))
 {
    echo "Error";
    return false;
}
return true;            
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textarea has no name assigned to it.

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Needs to be

```
<textarea name="message"></textarea>
```

You have this below, which not sure if you need this or not, but you will want to change the name of either the text area or this div to avoid a conflict.

```
<div class="textarea-size" id = "message" name = "message"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, now my page is automatically submitting and I can't figure out why

Comment: Based on the code your provided above (which isn't any at all, it's just html markup), it's nothing there. So you have more code that is causing that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is working correctly as per your form...
what you need to change is

```
<textarea class="textarea-size" id = "message" name = "message" ></textarea>
```

and remove the

```
<div class="textarea-size" id = "message" name = "message"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Because div tag is not have attribute "name" so when you submit it's cannot receive name="message". You should replace to a input :

```
<form id="register-form" name = "register-form" class="text-left" method="POST" action = "inp.php" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
    <div class="main-login-form">
        <div class="login-group">

            <div class="textarea-container">
                <textarea name="message"></textarea>

                       <div class="textarea-size" id="message"></div>
                        </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="login-button" w><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="etc-login-form">
        <p><font color = "white"></font> <a href="log.html"><font color = "black"></font></a></p>
    </div>
</form>
```